# Authentication and node.js: how do I render a page based on logged in user?

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, passport.js

So I'm new at authentication. I just setup my login using Passport and now my user is supposed to be logged in.

```
router.post('/login/data',
    passport.authenticate('local', {successredirect:'/', failureredir:'/login', failureFlash: true}),
    function(req, res) {
        // If this function gets called, authentication was successful.
        // `req.user` contains the authenticated user.
        res.redirect('/');
    });
```

It redirected me to my homepage, but now I would like it that every page in my app is different depending on the user that is logged in. How do I render my pages based on the logged-in user's data?

Comment: How are you rendering your pages?  Are you using templates?  Or is all client side javascript?

Comment: Hey man, I render my pages mostly with ejs files.

Comment: I'm wondering how I can access the data of the logged in user in, for example: res.render('index', {loggedInUserData: loggedInUserData}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the route for your homepage, you can check to see if there is a user authenticated, and if so, render a template with their data.

```
router.get('/', function(req, res){
   if (req.user) {
       res.render('index', { user: req.user });
   } else {
       res.redirect('/login');
   }
});
```

Then inside your `.ejs` file you will have access to the user's data.

```
<h1>Username: <%= user.username %></h1>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thank you very much sir. Have a nice day.